# Find the 0.95 quantile such that $P(Y \le \phi_{.95})=0.95$

Tags: integration, statistics

Suppose I have the density function $f(y) = 6y(1-y), 0 \le y \le 1$, find the 0.95 quantile such that $P(Y \le \phi_{.95})=0.95.$

What I have tried:

$$6\int_0^{\phi_{.95}}y(1-y)dy=6\left[\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3} \right]_0^{\phi_{.95}}=0.95$$

$$\implies6\left[\frac{(\phi_{.95})^2}{2}-\frac{(\phi_{.95})^3}{3} \right]=0.95$$

Now I'm not sure on how to proceed from here, the booklet answer shows $\phi_{0.95} = 0.865$, I had thought that I would have to re-arrange the integral result to find for $\phi$ though I cannot seem to isolate it.

Using the Newton approximation method as suggested

$$f(x_0)=f(x_0)-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$
When picking $f(x_0) = 0.95$

After I re-arranged the equation above into a cubic I get
$$\implies f(x_0) = 0.95-\frac{2(0.95)^3-3(0.95)^2+0.95}{6(0.95)^3-6(0.95)^2}\approx 0.8$$
$$\implies f(x_1) = 0.8-\frac{2(0.8)^3-3(0.8)^2+0.95}{6(0.8)^3-6(0.8)^2}\approx 0.865$$

Comment: Have you learned how to solve the cubic equation? Because, that is a cubic equation.

Comment: If we start with initial guess in the middle of the interval (0,1), [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for numerically solving that cubic equation gives the stated solution in four iterations.

Comment: @r.e.s. This is new to me and after trying it out I derived the right answer. Thanks for this new trick!

Comment: You're welcome. It's worth noting that your cubic equation has three roots that are all real (the one in [0,1] being the answer), and it can be shown that in such case none of them can be expressed in "closed form" in terms of real radicals. So numerical approximation (e.g. by Newton's method) is appropriate.

Comment: The distribution is $\mathsf{Beta}(2,2).$ (Perhaps see the Wikipedia article on 'beta distributions' if there is no discussion in your book.)  In R: `qbeta(.95, 2, 2)` returns $0.8646496,$ so it looks as if you've got it.